# Can I use ibus with xorg.conf rules?

Tags: x11, xorg, keyboard-layout, ibus

I just installed ibus. However, it appears to be overriding some of my `xorg.conf` rules. I have a file at `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-general-xkb.conf`, which includes the following line.

```
Option "XKbOptions" "lv3:ralt_switch_multikey,numpad:pc,ctrl:swapcaps"
```

This swaps <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>. However, my primary ergonomic keyboard already has these keys in the correct place. Hence, I have another file at `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/11-TECK-keymap.conf` that matches this keyboard (with `MatchProduct`), then applies the following line.

```
Option "XKbOptions" "lv3:ralt_switch_multikey,numpad:pc"
```

This overrides the previous options, leaving <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> as default.

However, after installing ibus, I'm finding that the second `xorg.conf` file is not firing correctly. After restarting my computer, or switching ibus layouts, I have the first, incorrect xorg layout, i.e. the `ctrl:swapcaps` option is incorrectly applied to my ergonomic keyboard. If I manually remove and plug back in the USB cable, then the layout is correct again. Is there a way to use ibus with `xorg.conf` rules?

FWIW the following is in `~/.xprofile`.

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
export QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
ibus-daemon -drx
```

I'm using KDE Plasma 5 and an up-to-date Arch Linux system.

### EDIT

If this is not possible, an ugly hack might be to rebind the "switch ibus layout" key to reload the `xorg.conf` rules after switching. I can't find a way to reload these rules though.